# MySQL full text index performance issue

Tags: mysql

I have created full-text index for one column like this 
        ALTER TABLE `test1` 
        ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `organizationname1` (`organizationname` ASC);

```
When I run this query 
    SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH(organizationname) AGAINST(' Limited');
    This query tack duration/ Fetch 0.061s/1.6700sec

but I am using like keyword in my  query 

 SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE organizationname like'%Limited%'
 This query tack duration/ Fetch 0.031s/0.071sec

** Now I want to know search performance?**
```

Comment: Please share create function AGAINST. you may use this query. show create function AGAINST;

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav in `MATCH (column) AGAINST (string)`, neither `MATCH` nor `AGAINST` is a stored function.   This is [MySQL fulltext search syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: @Eswer please repeat your queries using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM ...` to ensure that the performance difference is not coming from the query cache.  Mention the version of MySQL (`SELECT @@VERSION`) and include `SHOW CREATE TABLE test1;`.